# Page Bordering with an image?

Tags: graphics, framed, backgrounds

I want a custom border for my document.
I was thinking of doing something like this, creating a border with a graphics tool(only the outer frame) and then placing it in the beginning of the document, so it cover the entire page as a border.

When I type something now, would it be inside the frame or outside?

I need help in creating my own borders for the page.

Comment: You can either use the `textpos` or `tikz` package to position the image at an absolute position on the page. You might need to put that code in the header or footer, so that it is added on every page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package to add a frame to every page of your document; the package internally uses `PGF/TikZ` to place the background material and offers you great control over the attributes. A little example that places a blue frame in every page of the document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\Myframe{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
    \draw(0,0) rectangle (1.1\textwidth,1.15\textheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgHshift{-1cm}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgVshift{-0.1cm}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
  {\SetBgHshift{-1cm}}%
  {\SetBgHshift{1cm}}%
  \SetBgContents{\Myframe}\bg@material}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can use your own material as frame.

Comment: @Gonzola: \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}} isn't well because \thepage can be IV. or page IV or ... --- better \value{page}