# Draw a rectangle on page borders (not margins) with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

Let's assume that the blue rectangle in the next image 1 represents the page borders, the gray rectangle represents page margins and, the black one represents what I need to draw using Tikz.

[image: image 1]

I need it there as a background of my text, but  the tikz image align as a text on margins.

Comment: How about something like `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
 {\draw[line width=2mm,blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);}` If you are going to use this for all pages you can use the `background` package.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73611/10898 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18222/10898